# Make call to kinvey from angular test?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, kinvey

I need to create a user in kinvey and assert that the user has been added, all within an angular test. I am using the karma test runner.  All my of tests are timing out, and none of the code inside the kinvey promise blocks is being executed. How can I go about writing these tests?  Test code is below:

```
describe("Kinvey: Users", function() {

var key,
    secret;

beforeEach(function(){
    key = '...',
    secret = '...'


});


it("should create a user", function(done){


    var App = angular.module('App', ['kinvey']);

    App.run(['$kinvey', function($kinvey) {
    $kinvey.init({
        appKey: key,
        masterSecret: secret
    });

        var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.save('users', {
        username : 'gertrude@test.com'
        });

        promise().then(function(success){
            var query = new $kinvey.Query();
            query.equalTo('username', 'gertrude');
            var queryPromise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('users', query);
            return queryPromise().then(
                function(response){
                    console.log("response");
                    expect(response.username).to.equal("gertrude@test.com");

                    var destroyPromise = $kinvey.DataStore.destroy('users', response.id);

                    return destroyPromise().then(function(success){
                        return done();
                    }, function(error){
                        return done();
                    })
                }, function(error){
                    return null;
                })
        }, function(error){
            return null;
        });

    }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things:

- You are missing a call to [angular.bootstrap()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap), so the `run` block is never executed.
- The `$kinvey.init()` method is asynchronous. So, before calling `$kinvey.DataStore.save()` (or any other `$kinvey.*` method for that matter), make sure the init method finishes.
- It seems you are creating users by using `$kinvey.DataStore.save()` to the `users` collection. It is highly recommended that you use [`$kinvey.User.signup()`](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/users#signup) instead.

The best way to go forward is to move things to the `before` hook:

```
before(function(done) {
  this.App = angular.module('App', ['kinvey']);
  this.App.run(['$kinvey', function($kinvey) {
    $kinvey.init({
      appKey    : 'App Key',
      appSecret : 'App Secret'
    }).then(function() {
      done();
    }, function(error) {
      done(new Error(error.description));
    });
  }]);
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['kinvey']);
});
```

Now, in your test (`it` method), you can obtain a reference to `$kinvey` by doing:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'kinvey']);
$injector.invoke(function($kinvey) {
  // Do your tests with $kinvey.
});
```

Test away! I put a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywr8F/).

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library.